# clarification on probability answer

Tags: probability

I am studying for a test and I have a question that I do not understand how the answer was found.

Suppose that a professor sets a quiz with four $TRUE/FALSE$
questions and suppose that a student just randomly guesses each answer,

i.e., for each question she
writes “TRUE” with probability $\frac12$ and she writes “FALSE” with probability $\frac12$.

Suppose:

the 1st question is worth $1$ point

he 2nd question is worth $2$ points

the 3rd question is worth $4$ points

the 4th question is worth $8$ points.

Let Y be the total number of
points she gets.

Compute the following:

P(Y = 7)

The answer given is $\frac{1}{16}$

Now, from I understand, there is one way of getting seven points. The student can get 3 answers correctly, meaning questions, 1,2,and 3. So should the answer be $\frac18$?

Comment: Doesn't she need to also get #4 wrong?  (you didn't say there was a loss of points for an error).

Comment: There is no loss of points. Y represents the total she gets. So she would need to get 4 wrong.

Comment: ok. so it's $\frac18$ times the probability she gets one wrong, correct?

Comment: Yes.  Every particular pattern of $T,F$ has a $\frac 1{16}$ probability.  As you say, there's only one pattern that yields $7$ points, namely $TTTF$, so the answer is $\frac 1{16}$.